# How to switch b/w admob and facebook ads in android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, facebook-audience-network

I am developing a app in which I want to switch ads between admob and facebook audience network from my backend or admin panel. Can anyone help me implement this. Has anyone tried it, if yes then can you share your code and is it allowed on playstore. Looking forward to your response.
And I dont wish to use mediation. I wish to change from code.